# Can I call GenServer client functions from a remote node?

Tags: erlang, elixir, erlang-otp, gen-server

I have a GenServer on a remote node with both implementation and client functions in the module. Can I use the GenServer client functions remotely somehow?

Using `GenServer.call({RemoteProcessName, :"app@remoteNode"}, :get)` works a I expect it to, but is cumbersome.

If I want clean this up am I right in thinking that I'd have to write the client functions on the calling (client) node?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`:rpc.call/{4,5}`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/rpc.html#call-4) functions.

```
:rpc.call(:"app@remoteNode", MyModule, :some_func, [arg1, arg2])
```

Answer (score 3):

For large number of calls, It's better to user `gen_server:call/2-3`.
If you want to use `rpc:call/4-5`, you should know that it is just one process named `rex` on each node for handling all requests. So if it is running one `Mod:Func(Arg1, Arg2, Argn)`, It can not response to other request at this time !

Comment: That's useful to know, but does that mean I have to forgo the use of client functions in a GenServer, if I plan to use the GenServer to reply to multiple client processes?

Comment: Indeed -- the rpc module its used habitually by people coming from other languages, but I've acually never found a use-case for it, as you can just `Pid ! Message` or even spawn a process on a separate node directly (as long as it has access to the same code you're calling it on locally).

Comment: It's not about one gen_server. because one gen_server normally can send reply to requests sequentially. It's about having several gen_servers on remote node. So when you use rpc, only one of those gen_servers can reply to request at this time. If you don't want to disconnect from remote nodes often, You can load that module from remote node on current node dynamically and use its functions.

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR**

Yes

**Discussion**

There are PIDs, messages, monitors and links. Nothing more, nothing less. That is your universe. (Unless you get into some rather esoteric aspects of the runtime implementation -- but at the abstraction level represented by EVM languages the previously stated elements (should) constitute your universe.)

Within an Erlang environment (whether local or distributed in a mesh) *any* PID can send a message addressed to *any other* PID (no middle-man required), as well as establish monitors and so on.

`gen_server:cast` sends a gen_server packaged message (so it will arrive in the form `handle_cast/2` will be called on). `gen_server:call/2` establishes a monitor and a timeout for receiving a labeled reply. Simply doing `PID ! SomeMessage` does essentially the same thing as `gen_server:cast` (sends a message) without any of the gen_server machinery behind it (messier to abstract as an interface).

That's all there is to it.

With this in mind, *of course* you can use `gen_server:call/2` across nodes, as long as they are connected into a cluster/mesh via disterl. Two disconnected nodes would have to communicate a different way (network sockets) and wouldn't have any knowledge of each other's internal mapping of PIDs, but as long as disterl is being used they all translate PIDs amongst themselves quite readily. Named processes is where things get a little tricky, but that is the purpose of the `global` module and utilities such as `gproc` (though dependence on such facilities beyond a certain point is usually an indication of an architectural problem).

Of course, just because PIDs from any node can communicate with PIDs from another node doesn't always means they *should*. The physical topology of the network (bandwidth, latency, jitter) comes into play when you start sending high-frequency or large messages (lots of `gen_server:call`s), and you have always got to think of partition tolerance -- but for off-loading heavy sorts of work (rare) or physically partitioning sub-systems within a very large system (more common) directly sending messages is a very simple way to take a program coded for a single node and distribute it across a cluster.

(With all that in mind, it is somewhat rare to see the rpc module used.)